# Why isn't `ruby -e` working within Powershell?

Tags: ruby, powershell

I've just finished building and installing the latest Ruby, version 2.0.0-p247 on Windows 8. (Note: I've also tested with the prebuilt RubyInstaller with same results)

Attempting to execute a simple Hello World example from the command line yields two different results depending on whether ruby is launched from Powershell, or cmd.

```
Powershell:
.\ruby -e 'puts "Hello, World!"' # -e:1: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input

cmd:
.\ruby -e 'puts "Hello, World!"' # Hello, World!
```

Any ideas why ruby is failing from within the Powershell environment?

Note: Windows 8 includes Powershell 3.0 (haven't tested with 1.0 or 2.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cmd.exe, the single quote characters are passed along to ruby, whereas in Powershell they are interpreted as enclosing a single-quote string literal.

This might work (Powershell syntax to pass the string with value `'puts "Hello!"'` (including the single quotes):

```
PS> ruby -e "'puts `"Hello!`"'"
```

If not, you can lean on the new PS v3 "stop parsing" symbol `--%`

```
PS> ruby -e --% 'puts "Hello!"'
```

Comment: Excellent! Worked a charm. (the stop parsing form at least) The first form unfortunately still does not work, but I think I like the second form better anyhow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The ruby alias is add into the command prompt when ruby is installed.  I do not think that they also add a alias for Powershell.  To run this you will have to set the path to where ruby is installed, and then run the command.

Example:

```
Cd C:\Ruby193\bin
ruby -e 'puts "Hello, World!"'
```

Comment: Since I compiled and installed ruby myself, this is actually what I'm currently doing. I figured I'd configure my PATH once everything was working. The error provided is actually a ruby error, so I'm certain ruby is being invoked correctly. I've updated my question to reflect the fact that I'm invoking ruby from the current directory, rather than performing a PATH search.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I misunderstood.